# jQuery AJAX Post doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I can't figure out why the following code doesn't work.  For the time being, the php function "alias_valid"  just returns a string for testing purposes, so I haven't included the php function here. The alert is empty.

```
$.post(SITE_ROOT + "includes/AbstractEvent.php",{
    action:"alias_valid", 
    alias : alias},
    function(v){
        alert(v);
    });
```

Comment: Please include the PHP. If you are returning, as in using `return`, that is the problem. You should be using `echo`.

Comment: I've tried both ways, but here is the function:
 function alias_valid(){
  echo "reached";
 }

Comment: Is `SITE_ROOT` correctly set ? Try hardcoding the whole url instead of using this `SITE_ROOT`.

Comment: Is that `alias_valid` function actually called from within your PHP script?

Comment: SITE_ROOT is correctly set.  If it wasn't, it would give me a 404 error because it wouldn't find the php file, right?  Plus, I checked it, and it is correct.

Comment: What do you mean is the alias_valid function called from within my PHP script?

Comment: @barkingmonkey What I mean is: does your php script just follow the logic of `<?php function alias_valid() {echo 'something';} ?>` and you are just expecting that "action" in `.post()` will help launch it? If yes - that's not how it works unless a framework takes care of it for you. If no - maybe try taking a look at your logs (make sure they are enabled) on the server side? Does php really receive the request? Does it reach the `alias_valid` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `action` argument in [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). Try to concatenate it to the end of the url instead.

```
$.post(SITE_ROOT + "includes/AbstractEvent.php/alias_valid/",{ 
    alias : alias},
    function(v){
        alert(v);
    });
```

But i doubt this will work unless you are using an MVC framework. Or some kind of request routing that calls the specific function within the class.

Comment: Yup and it won't you're trying to call a function within a class ?

Comment: Yest, but I've also put it outside the class.

Answer (score 1):

> If a request with jQuery.post() returns an error code, it will fail
>   silently

Try `.error()` to check if there is any error happening

Syntax:

```
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqxhr object for this request
var jqxhr = $.post("example.php", function() {
  alert("success");
})
.success(function() { alert("second success"); })
.error(function() { alert("error"); })
.complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

[More info on $.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that one of your variables is undefined. Verify that `SITE_ROOT` and `alias` are indeed defined within your code. Also check if the `SITE_ROOT` ends in `/`.

The best way to test all that would be to launch your console (press <kbd>F12</kbd>) and see what errors you get. If there are none, you might be getting an empty response from the server.

Here's a [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4CdB/) based on your example (again, press <kbd>F12</kbd>to access the output in the console).

Comment: SITE_ROOT does end in /.  It contains the correct directory.  And alias is defined in the code.  Besides, I even got rid of that part, and it still wouldn't work.